# jQuery add one text box inside a td and prevent adding more if click event occured second time inside the same cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I typed a script which add an `input` with `type=text` inside of a clicked td, with the original value of the `td` inside of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#med_table').on('click', '.tdSel', function() {
        var num_pills = ($(this).text());
        $(this).val("");
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="number" id="test" class="form-control select" value='+num_pills+'>')
        $('#test').on('focusout', function()
        {
            var new_quantity = $(this).val();
            //console.log(new_quantity);
            //alert("out");
            //Ajax
        })
    });
})
```

My problem is that if I clicked by mistake another time on the same `td` another text box is added. What I want is to add one single text box on the clicked `td`.

I tried to set a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('#med_table').on('click', '.tdSel', function() {
        if(i==0)
        {
            var num_pills = ($(this).text());
            $(this).val("");
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            $(this).replaceWith('<input type="number" id="test" class="form-control select" value='+num_pills+'>')
            $('#test').on('focusout', function()
            {
                var new_quantity = $(this).val();
                //console.log(new_quantity);
                //alert("out");
                //Ajax
            })
        }
        i++;
    });
})
```

It worked but now I can't add text boxes inside other `tds`.

Comment: Use the `counter` on `.data()` on each `td`.

Comment: Can you please create your code example at this: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

HTML:

```
<table border = "1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").on("click", function() {
        var counter = $(this).attr("data-counter");
        if (counter != 1) {
            var data = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="number" id="test" class="form-control select" value=' + data + '>');
            $(this).attr("data-counter", "1");
        }
    });
});
```

Try the live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ynpz836a/)

Comment: Can you explain what is data-counter ?

Comment: `data-counter` is the html tag's attribute which is added run time.

Example: `<td data-counter='1'></td>`